# Running Binary logistic regression with interaction terms vs running it on a subset of data

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, interaction, model

I am trying to run a binary logistic regression that predicts the probability of infection based on a series of categorical predictor variables, and one continuous variable.

Here is the structure:

```
    'data.frame':   327 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ District        : Factor w/ 7 levels "10th of Ramadan city",..: 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
 $ Species         : Factor w/ 4 levels "Chicken","Duck",..: 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Breed           : Factor w/ 8 levels "Baladi","Broiler",..: 2 2 2 1 7 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Age             : num  8 8 10 8 8 8 6 8 8 8 ...
 $ Breeding system : chr  "farm" "backyard" "backyard" "farm" ...
 $ Type of sample  : Factor w/ 2 levels "organs","Tracheal swabs": 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Infection       : Factor w/ 2 levels "negative","postive": 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

The predictor variable (Species) is 4 birds, and the (Breed) is different breeds within each of those species, the same for Age, which differs among species, and also breeding system. So, I realized I can not run regression on the predictors (other than species) as there is an interaction with species.
My question is: Is it better to divide the data into 4 different sets, one for each bird species and then run univariate logistic regression for each variable (here there is no interaction) and then run multivariate regression on significant ones. OR: I run the multivariate on the whole data using an interaction.

I assume the interaction one should be like this:

```
model <- glm (Infection ~ Species * Breed * Breeding system * Age * type of sample, data = Data, family = "Binomial")
```

Also, the $\beta$ coefficient produced after running the interaction would be the probability of each variable ignoring from the belongingness to each species so basically accounting for different species? Is that true? How to interpret the results of the interaction?

Comment: I suggest asking yourself whether you expect *any* of the effects of the predictors to be common across species. If so, analyzing the 4 datasets simultaneously will lead to greater efficiency of these effect estimates. Otherwise, you can just analyze the 4 datasets separately -- with no cost, just increased simplicity of the output.